# Dynamic array for queries in google sheets with imported ranges

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm wondering if there's any way to build a dynamic range into a query, so it automatically adds new imported ranges if I add them onto a sheet. I saw an example on here for within sheets, but I can't see how it would translate to imported ones. I've done an example here:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fPoi4x5H7uowBFyo1kbxTY_us6snW7juJVPxZHfi7SM/edit#gid=0

I've got 3 data sheets that are already there that would have been built into the recipient sheet to start with using an apps script generator, which concatenates the original query, but this was built by someone else, I'm still pretty new to apps script. Whenever I add new people to a recipient sheet I need to go and stick the URL of their sheet in there, which is not an issue and probably something someone else can do.

However I then need to go to another sheet and manually edit the query every time, which is something that other people in my team probably can't do without ruining things. I'm wondering if the textjoin output in cell B9, based on the joins in column A when pulled down could in some way serve as the data argument in the query function, similar to sticking a separate query statement in cell A1, as then they'd just have to pull the formula down when adding the sheet. I could probably concatenate up an entire query function for someone to copy and paste into the query cell, but that's getting a bit too close to letting someone into the protected cells, haha.

Any ideas? I'm not very hot on indirect which I thought could be an option. If it's not possible it's not possible, but as ever, would be nice if it could.
Cheers,
Meg

Edit: I forgot to mention the original data is from transposed importranges if that makes a difference, but when I started making the dummy sheet I lost track of how I'd done that in the first place...

Comment: Apologies, but I don't think I understood the issue. You have a "main" Sheets file that uses IMPORTRANGEs grab data from different other Sheets files (to make a "UNION"/"JOIN" if this was a DB), and then a QUERY is done to the resulting "union dataset"?

The actual query in the QUERY formula is a string tho, you can always concatenate other imported cells for example and "build" your query dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One cannot use the `IMPORTRANGE` function the way you wish *(concatenate or join)*. But.

#### You have an alternative.

Use the following formula.

```
=QUERY(QUERY({IFERROR({IMPORTRANGE(C3,E1)},{"",""}); 
              IFERROR({IMPORTRANGE(C4,E1)},{"",""});
              IFERROR({IMPORTRANGE(C5,E1)},{"",""});
              IFERROR({IMPORTRANGE(C6,E1)},{"",""});
              IFERROR({IMPORTRANGE(C11,E1)},{"",""});
              IFERROR({IMPORTRANGE(C8,E1)},{"",""});
              IFERROR({IMPORTRANGE(C21,E1)},{"",""});
              IFERROR({IMPORTRANGE(C15,E1)},{"",""});
              IFERROR({IMPORTRANGE(C7,E1)},{"",""})}),
           "where Col1 <>'' ")
```

[image]

#### How the formula works

What you do is predict how many links you may have and pre-fill them within your query.

As you see the basic part is:

```
IFERROR({IMPORTRANGE(your_link_cell_here,E1)},{"",""})
```

You can pre-fill as many parts as you wish.

*(You need to other formula or helper columns. Even if you later need more you can just add them.)*

Comment: This looks like a really great workaround, cheers! Would it work the same if I transposed the data within the importranges? I can't see any reason why not, but just to check.

Comment: *"... cheers!"* You're welcome.  About your question: *"...transposed the data within the importranges"*. I don't quite understand what you mean. In any case you can just give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

### The Concatenation Formula

> **Paste** this formula in `E3` to Create and Concatenate the formula, **No need to drag down** and paste ID's instead of url's in column `B`  take a look at this [**Sheet.**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1by28u-AnyXkQGDS63RsHVckgw6oX5ts794bbqKClSzY/edit?usp=sharing).

```
=CONCATENATE("= { ", TEXTJOIN("; ",1,ArrayFormula(SUBSTITUTE(CONCATENATE("IMPORTRANGE( ", """#"""," ,",$E$2, " )"),"#" ,FILTER(B3:B,B3:B<>"")))), " } ")
```

> Now you can copy and paste the formula to the `D6`.

[image]

**Note:** there is not similar to Excel EVALUATE() function in google sheets to evaluate text in cell to a formula.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I think I wasn't too clear with what I needed. There's no issue with the data in the data sheets themselves, nothing's going to be added there that means I would need a named range, it's that I've got a query which pulls data from three sheets, and I'd like it to auto update to pull data from 4 sheets. If I used a named range on the main sheet columns I'm assuming it wouldn't really work because the range I'm wanting to update is actually a string within the range itself?

Comment: ok i got you now if  want to add anther range in the main sheet cell  `A6` and down ? the formula updates ?

Comment: Basically if you copy and paste another URL in column C (e.g. for sheet 4) then you can drag the formula in column A down to cover it, which I haven't done in the example one, so then it adds another string to the textjoin when you do - it's a bit fiddly, haha.

Comment: when the answer is updated you dont need a the url just the sheet ID, haha *i guss*.

Comment: Cheers, but the issue is that I need it to fit into a query - the actual query is more complex than the example one. Is there a way to take the formula in E3 which /does/ automatically update itself and use it directly as the data range in D6, without needing to copy and paste? I'm trying to make it so someone in the admin team could just paste a URL/sheet ID in column B and not need to update the query formula itself. If you look at my sheet I've already got a textjoin in B9 and concat formula in C9 which update when I drag down in A to cover sheet 4, but can't make it work as a formula.

Comment: Hi @Meg **1st thing  there is no similar function to Excel's EVALUATE() function in Google Sheets to evaluate text in a cell to a formula. **2 in this example, you dont need to drag down to concatinate, just add more sheets ID's to the list. **3 i did make it a little easier by concatinating the formula to copy, but in terms of protection and team involvement, eeh it's not that much of an improvement.

Comment: Ah fair - I thought it might not be possible but intrigued to hear about the excel one - I don't know much about excel at all. I didn't spot that about your formula at first, definitely simplifies it a bit, so will probably try to work on that and let go of my control freakiness! Thanks so much for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use named func:

```
=IFERROR(
    UNIQUE(IMPORTRANGE(VLOOKUP(number;Links!$A$1:$D;4;FALSE);"Sheet!A2:T"));
    {" ERROR  "& VLOOKUP(number;Links!$A$1:$D;2;FALSE) &" "\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\number})
```

And use array:

```
=UNIQUE(SORT({
  GET_DATA(1)
  ;GET_DATA(2)
  ;GET_DATA(3)
  ;GET_DATA(4)
  ;GET_DATA(5)
  ;GET_DATA(6)
  ;GET_DATA(7)
  ;GET_DATA(8)
  ;GET_DATA(9)
  ;GET_DATA(10)
};20;TRUE))
```