# Array of IMPORTRANGEs in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

For this sample table:

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Range!A1:C5 | URL1 | **= Formula here** |  |  |
| 2 |  | URL2 |  |  |  |
| 3 |  | URL3 |  |  |  |
| 4 |  | ... |  |  |  |

I have this **working** formula in C1:

```
={IMPORTRANGE(B1, A1); IMPORTRANGE(B2, A1); IMPORTRANGE(B3, A1)}
```

A1 contains the range to pull from the target Sheets.

Links to the target Sheets are found in column B.

(This is a simplified example. My actual Sheet has 21 entries in column B.)

##### Question:

If I will have to **add/remove URLs** in column B, I have to **adjust the formula** in C1 and add/remove IMPORTRANGEs.

I would like to have **a formula that automatically adjusts to the entries in column B.**

##### Solutions tried:

I tried this, but it did not work:

```
={JOIN("", ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B1:B), "IMPORTRANGE(""" & B1:B & """, """ & A1 & """); ", "")))}
```

The `JOIN` function returns a text that should be identical to what the array `{ ... }` parses as a formula. But it doesn't. Wrapping it with `INDIRECT` also does not work.

Any suggestions on how I could make this work?

Answer (score 0):

if by "working formula" you mean valid formula that returns data then only thing you can do is hardcode it like this:

```
=QUERY({
 IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE(B1, A1), {"","",""}); 
 IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE(B2, A1), {"","",""}); 
 IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE(B3, A1), {"","",""})}, 
 "where Col1 is not null", )
```

`A1:C5` = 3 columns = `{"","",""}`

you can generate formula dynamically with arrayformula but the result will be always a text string and not active formula. tho if you wanna go this way you will need a script that will convert your text string into active formula. example:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/73119313/5632629
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61819704/5632629